# Get svnversion with git-svn

Tags: git-svn

with `git svn` I can use a svn repository with git. In svn, I can get version of revision with

```
svnversion
```

how I can get the version of svn revision with `git svn`?

Answer (score 3):

```
git svn info | grep '^Revision: ' | cut -c 11-
```

- `git svn info` displays some information including the current revision
- `grep '^Revision: '` extracts from this the line where the current revision is mentioned
- `cut -c 11-` extracts the actual revision number from it by cutting off the first 10 characters which are `Revision:`

Answer (score 0):

The @Vampire answer is pretty good, I'd just like to include just one more command, in case you want to get the revision of a specific commit, instead the last one of the repository:

```
git svn log
```

This command will list all the commits that you have into the SVN repository, giving the SVN revision, author, timestamp, lines edited, and the commit message.